# Multiple Instances Of Daloradius Authenticating from One Freeradius

Tags: freeradius, radius

I am working on a project where I need to set up multiple instances of daloRADIUS, each running on a separate subdomain, and all of them authenticating through a single FreeRADIUS server. While setting up multiple instances of daloRADIUS is straightforward, I am encountering challenges in ensuring that each daloRADIUS instance has segregated data, relevant only to its specific subdomain.

Here's the context of what I'm trying to achieve:

Multiple ISPs/Subdomains: Each daloRADIUS instance corresponds to a different ISP or subdomain.
Single FreeRADIUS Server: All daloRADIUS instances authenticate through a single FreeRADIUS server.
Data Isolation: Each daloRADIUS instance should only access and manage data relevant to its specific subdomain/ISP, without any overlap.
I am looking for guidance or suggestions on how to configure the database and FreeRADIUS server to ensure data isolation among the multiple daloRADIUS instances.

tried using realms but it actually didnt work